# Flex 3 - Getting focusedIndex in a buttonbar

Tags: apache-flex, focus, indexing, mouseover, buttonbar

I've been looking around on how to get the focusedIndex property of a ButtonBar when there's a mouseOver/Out event, but haven't found nothing useful.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Regards,
BS_C3

---

EDIT 1

Assuming we have this button bar:

[image: buttonbar]

I'd like to know, when rolling over, the target button.

Putting a break point in a function that listens to the mouseover event, this is what I see in the debug view:

[image: focusedIndex]

As you can see, there's a focusedIndex variable that's is strangely not documented...

Comment: What do you expect a "focusIndex" property to do?  What informations hould such a property provide you?  Would selectedIndex work?

Comment: I'm using a custom tooltip that is launched when the user does a mouse over/out on a button from the buttonbar. While debugging and inspecting the variables of the mouseOver event, I found that there was a variable called "focusedIndex"... Knowing the index would help me retrieve the data I need from the dataprovider of the buttonbar.

Comment: There is no documented property named focusedIndex in the MouseEvent class: https://www.flextras.com/MobileComponents/Samples/SquareButtonSample/ .  Do you want to know which button the mouse cursor is over?

Comment: That's indeed what I'd like to know... However, the buttonbar does not receive the same data as a simple button... >.< I just added a EDIT 1 where you can see the focusedIndex I'm talking about. I know it's not documented... which surprised me cause I'm seing it in my debug view...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is an mx_internal value.

Just use this magic when yo do imports:

```
import mx.core.mx_internal;
use namespace mx_internal;
```

Then you should be able to access the value in your button bar's mouse hander w/o issues:

```
trace(e.target.focusedIndex);
```

As a point of clarification; the property on the ButtonBar class; not on the event class, like you originally stated.  The ButtonBar instance is embedded inside the Mouse Event.  I've heard that called Nested Objects before.

Comment: Hi! This works great! The next issue I'm having is that I cannot use 'use namespace mx_internal' cause I'm using the StyleManager to set styles. So I'm getting the error "1000: Ambiguous reference to setStyle". I tried some tricks (http://sherifabdou.com/2008/09/1000-ambiguous-reference-to-setstyle/) but cannot make it work. Would you have any clue? Thanks :)

Comment: If there is an ambiguous reference; you have to solve it by fully classifying the class name before the method call; and possibly specifying the namespace for the mx_internal namespaces.  I think you can probably removed the "use" command and replace the trace with e.target.mx_internal::focusedIndex or something similar.  I forget the exact syntax off top of my head.  You'd need to provide more code to get a more concrete answer.

Comment: Well, I finally stopped using the StyleManager... I tried to use e.target.mx_internal::focusedIndex but that did not work... :( Thanks for all your answers and help :)

Comment: I must have the syntax wrong on that.  Glad it helped, though.

Comment: Your syntax is not wrong... I saw the same syntax in quite some places... but it just did not work >.<